# how to write custom function in wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

how to write a custom function in WordPress just like Codeigniter or laravel?
I want to access the custom function like as website.com/custom_function.

```
function custom_function()
{
 echo "this is a custom function.";
}
```

please give me the way thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Three ways to add your custom function in wordpress

1. Functions.php file (here you can add your custom function)
2. by creating custom plugin
3. creating your custom_function file and enqueue and register file through functions.php

Comment: in point 1, how can I call the custom function on the browser. please guide me.

Comment: function testing()
{
 echo "testing";
}

i added this function in functions.php file and how can i call it to browser which show me "testing"?